# multiprocessing.pool.apply_async: do I need to `get` results?

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to achieve a fire-and-forget call of an output function with can take any time.

The caller is not interested at all whether this function is successful or not. It should just dispatch a "message", and move on.

I am thinking to use a multiprocessing.Pool for this task and "dispatch the messages" with [`apply_async`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async). Usually one would use `get()` to get the result, but in my case that would complicate the code slightly. So I am thinking of never actually calling `get()`. Is that legal, or is this going to cause a cache (with `None` returns) somewhere to blow up after a while?

Comment: according to apply_async docs you don't have to specify a callback